# Is it good practice to remove un-used namespaces in C# class files which are generated by Visual Studio?

Tags: c#

Several namespaces are automatically used when a class file is created by Visual Studio:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Some of them are used in code, but some seems are not. Is it good practice to delete the ones which are not used?

Comment: It will speed up your build time. Other than that, in the generated dlls, those stuff got removed by the compiler.

Comment: Here is a link from programmers stackexchange http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/126996/what-are-the-consequences-of-having-unnecessary-references-and-usings

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026820/do-unused-usings-in-net-affect-performance

Comment: _"It will speed up your build time"_ - I don't believe there is sufficient evidence for that mentioned in the links you provided

Comment: You might check this question for some discussion of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774624/does-using-namespaces-affect-performance-or-compile-time. As is said there, it cannot affect runtime performance. If you look at generated IL code, you'll see that it always uses full type name. The `using` statements only help keep you code cleaner, but the compiler effectively removes them.